# How to populate one combobox based on another combobox selection in a setup project using Visual Studio 2010 Setup and Deployment Project?

Tags: combobox, installation, windows-installer, setup-project, orca

I have created a custom dialog where in I have two comboboxes in my dialog using orca tool for MSI but now I'm stuck with populating a combobox based on another combobox selection in a MSI either using orca tool or using the windows installer.

Please guide me
Thanks

Comment: It would take too long to explain how to do this in Orca, and there are so many details of names, events, custom actions etc that it couldn't be explained by another person. You should try using WiX and look at Publishing events in the UI. That would be easier than Orca.

Comment: @PhilDW its ok if it takes time but can you please help me out cause this is causing me alot of trouble as of now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, it woud take literally al my time for a week. You really should use WiX, for example, and just use WiX. Nobody attempts what you are doing with Orca.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW will you please let me know how to do a conditional  installation of a service using WiX....I'm pretty much new to WiX....

Comment: Create two identical components, except that one has a differend ID of course, then use a condition to install the appropriate one. If it's a property, use the WiX remember property pattern to keep it consisten in repairs. Or ask it as a new question and see if you get other answers.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW  I'll look in to the solution